# Regex Expression for Specific string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regex expression so not able to validate the String which can have number 0-9 FGHC,and fghc *#.

I am trying with
 `[0-9FGHCFGHC*#]`its working with regex tool but in java its not working.I am using java 1.7

E.g.for this pattern I required it like 
`2314F*Ghc
12fgH#`etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String money = "23FGhc*#";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9FGHCfghc*#]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(money);
    if (m.matches())
        System.out.println("valid:-"+ m);
    else
        System.out.println("unvalid:- "+m);
}
```

Thank in Advance for your help and it will be more help that you explain the soultion so I can have more knowledge in RegEx

Comment: You forgot the [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag and perhaps a quantifier (`+`) at the end.

Comment: I tried with that also,but no luck:(

Comment: Please show the exact relevant code. There are a bunch of questions like my regex does not work in Java but works at regex101, and the reasons can be different: 1) missed flag, 2) did not execute the Matcher, 3) used matches instead of find (and vice versa).

Comment: Ok, you did not use `+` or `*` at the end (and at the regex tester, you had `/g` modifier to enable global match). Do not use regexr.com, use regex101.com. The answer below is correct.

Comment: yeah that is true...Thanks for you comment.it'll give me help to understand more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?i)[0-9fghc*#]+
```

You need to add a quantifier at the end as well. In this case `+` to match these characters one or more times.

Use can also add `(?i)` to make it case insensitive.